# How do I determine the network within a truffle exec script?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I'm writing a script to be executed with `truffle exec` and I need to add some logic conditional on the network we're calling `truffle exec` with.

This is (roughly) what I want in my script:

```
const contract = artifacts.require("./MyContract.sol");
module.exports = function(callback) {
  // TODO: Do some conditional thing based on network!

  contract.callMethod();
}
```

I'm hoping to call this script in the following way:

```
truffle exec script.js --network ropsten
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best method, but the arguments you pass to `truffle`, including the network, are available under `process.argv`.

**script.js**:

```
process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```

Then:

```
> truffle exec script.js --network development
Using network 'development'.

0: /usr/bin/node
1: /usr/bin/truffle
2: exec
3: foo.js
4: --network
5: development
```

So access that array at the relevant index for the network name.

Comment: In which case, the `--network` argument is redundant. Unlike `truffle migrate` and `truffle deploy` (which are identical btw), `truffle exec` and `truffle test` do not receive the network as an argument, so one has to pass it explicitly and then access it via `process.argv`.

Comment: Ah, good point - which must be why it's outputting the line `Using network 'development'`, i.e. "I don't know which network to use, so using the first one in the config file."

Comment: Actually, now that you've mentioned it... It kinda makes me think that perhaps `truffle test` **can** somehow be configured with a specific network. I guess it'll require looking into their source code...

Comment: Not the cleanest, but this works! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **web3.eth.network** api .

```
'use strict';

global.artifacts = artifacts;
global.web3 = web3;

async function main(){
    const newtworkType = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType();
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    console.log("network type:"+newtworkType);
    console.log("network id:"+networkId);
}

// For truffle exec
module.exports = function(callback) {
    main().then(() => callback()).catch(err => callback(err))
};
```

I hope it can be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

[As of Aug 2020](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/3233) Truffle makes the `config` global available to scripts. The `network` property is set in the usual way.

```js
module.exports = function(callback) {
  const network = config.network;
  if (network == 'development') {
     ...
  }
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can find the "--network" position argument inside **process.argv** and following logic next one should be the network name:

```
module.exports = async (callback) => {
const networkIndex = process.argv.findIndex(arg => arg === '--network');
const networkName = process.argv[networkIndex + 1];
console.log(networkName);

callback();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define your network in truffle-config.js

For example:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {
  test: {
    host: `127.0.0.1`,
    port: 9999,
    network_id: 3,
    gas: 5500000,
    confirmations: 2,
    timeoutBlocks: 200,
    skipDryRun: true
  },
  ropsten: {
    provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonicOrPrivatekey, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/${infuraKey}`),
    network_id: 3,
    gas: 5500000,
    confirmations: 2,
    timeoutBlocks: 200,
    skipDryRun: true
  },
}
```

Then you can run script with `--network test`